# How to program a mouse click on Mac OS X and on Linux?

Tags: linux, user-interface, macos, winapi, click

I know how to program a click on Win32 (click on the screen programmatically) using C or Ruby.  Does anyone know how to do it on Mac OS X and Linux just as a comparison?  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OS X, there are various approaches (i.e. Carbon, Cocoa, Apple Events) to programming a mouse click described in the article and comments [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2008051406323031).

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question myself recently on identi.ca, and got the following answers:

"You can try XSendEvent in Xlib or xcb_send_event in XCB."

"Try a small utility called xte (part of the xautomation package.)"

I also found a tool called [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) which allows you to programatically simulate keyboard and mouse activity, amongst other things.